# Removing line form file containing $A but not $B

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to remove from a text file all lines that

- contains the variable $A
- but not if it as well contains variable $B

Currently I've something like that:

```
sed -e '/${VAR_A_TO_BE_DELETED}/ {/${VAR_B_DONT_DELETE}/! s/$VAR_A_TO_BE_DELETED/STRING_TO_MARK_DELETION/}' $FILE_NAME | grep -v STRING_TO_MARK_DELETION > temp_file; mv temp_file $FILE_NAME
```

Is there a more elegant way? this seems to not work not always (still have to figure out what are the parameter for "not working").

Comment: When doesn't it work?  When you have two instances of $A on the line?  You forgot a `g` at the end of the `s///`.  It is approximately as good as it gets.  You could use `n;` in place of `!`.

Comment: I'm very confused.  Are you trying to match text that is in a variable named `$VAR_A_TO_BE_DELETED`?  If so, you're using the wrong quotes and the shell is not interpolating that variable.  If you're looking for the literal text `${VAR_A_TO_BE_DELETED}`, then I don't understand why the braces are missing in the `s///` command.  Please edit the question for precision.

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant way to do what you're currently trying to do with sed+grep is to just use awk:

```
awk -v a="$VAR_A_TO_BE_DELETED" -v b="$VAR_B_DONT_DELETE" '
    ($0 ~ b) || !($0 ~ a)
' "$FILE_NAME" > temp_file && 
mv temp_file "$FILE_NAME"
```

and, since you said sometimes that doesn't work and guessing that's due to regexp metacharacters in your variable contents, the right way to do it instead using string operations instead of regexp:

```
awk -v a="$VAR_A_TO_BE_DELETED" -v b="$VAR_B_DONT_DELETE" '
    index($0,b) || !index($0,a)
' "$FILE_NAME" > temp_file && 
mv temp_file "$FILE_NAME"
```

If your variables can contain backslashes, e.g. `\t` then the above will expand them, e.g. to a tab character. If that's a problem then you'd either add a backslash before each backslash in the variable assignments or do this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        a=ARGV[2]; ARGV[2]=""; ARGC--
        b=ARGV[3]; ARGV[3]=""; ARGC--
    }
    index($0,b) || !index($0,a)
' "$FILE_NAME" "$VAR_A_TO_BE_DELETED" "$VAR_B_DONT_DELETE" > temp_file && 
mv temp_file "$FILE_NAME"
```